# BotFramework CardAction.postBack support for Skype

Tags: botframework

I am attempting to present a HeroCard to a Skype user that contains one or more buttons that should perform a postBack to my API. My understanding is that the postBack (unlike imBack) is not supposed to display the message being posted back to my API from the Skype client.

Here is the gist of what I am doing...

```
// loop through a list of quickReplies. Add each button to an array.
{
    buttons.push(botBuilder.CardAction.postBack(session, quickReply.payload, quickReply.title));
}

// Create the HeroCard response.
var card = new botBuilder.Message(session)
    .textFormat(botBuilder.TextFormat.xml)
    .attachments([
        new botBuilder.HeroCard(session)
            .buttons(buttons)
    ]);

session.send(card);
```

The buttons of the HeroCard render just fine on the Skype client, but when I click one, the quickReply.payload is displayed similar to how the imBack works. I would have expected no reply to be displayed, but my API would receive the message containing the quickReply.payload.

The BotFramework emulator seems to handle the postBack functionality just fine.

Searching 'postBack' through the SDK did not turn up anything obvious.

Does anyone know if CardAction.postBack is not supported for BotFramework/Skype? Or am I simply doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

postBack is not supported by Skype. Only the following action types are supported by Skype: *openUrl, imBack, call, showImage, signin*

[Here](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/attachments.html#cardaction) is the documentation article that mention this.

Comment: Oh my goodness... I read right over that multiple times. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: So, we can use postback as an action in hero card ?